# NiFi / ElasticSearch: Date Failed to Parse

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-nifi

I'm using NiFi to put some data into ElasticSearch. I created the following ES index:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/test_index -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
"index_patterns" : ["test_index"],
"mappings" : {
    "doc"  : {
        "properties" : {
            "example1" :  { "type": "text" },
            "example2" :     { "type": "text" },
            "Date" :         
                { "type": "date",
                  "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

This loads into ES, no problem. But, the `Date` object coming through my NiFi flow is this:

```
"Date" : "Fri, 09 Nov 2018 18:30:49 GMT"
```

And my `PutElasticsearchHttp` processor gives me an error:

```
ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] o.a.n.p.e.PutElasticsearchHttp 
PutElasticsearchHttp[id=55b31b9a-3319-124c-4ede-0d3e8c02e9cb] Failed to 
process StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=5b6d8fc7-0dfd-435d-8a5c- 
adb4cdb08495,claim=StandardContentClaim 
[resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1541788260542-269, 
container=default, section=269], offset=176034, 
length=187],offset=0,name=ba74c484-9719-418f-a665- 
7b7d492b40a4,size=187] due to failed to parse [Date], transferring to 
failure
```

Do I need to change the date format? (Perhaps through `UpdateAttribute`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you need to format the date in nifi to a more common like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 or set a custom date format in your es mapping.

please have a look on patterns described here: https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html

if you need to know how define a custom date mapping in es, have a look on this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't help me formatting the "Fri," at the beginning of the date string. Going off this seems simple: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/191291/how-to-convert-string-to-date-in-nifi.html , but the "Fri" screws things up

Comment: It's coming through like this now, `"Fri, 09 Nov 2018 18:30:49 GMT"`, but ES can't parse that

Comment: this is not the format pattern, this is the already formated timestamp. this is a pattern: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ

Comment: Oh. Just needed someone to tell me that, I guess. Not anywhere on the internet. Thanks

Comment: glad the answer worked for you. please consider marking your question answered for future research of other SO users